# unreal engine blueprint actor lost parameter after files move location

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unrealscript, unreal-umg

I created three files, one material, one enum, one blueprint actor. In blueprint actor, I created a dynamic material instance to access material and a variable to access enum as a dropdown list. This functions all work fine, but when I move these three files to others' PC, the blueprint actor become doesn't work, the dynamic material instance lost material parameter and the type of the variable I created are not enum anymore. Is that means I have to set these parameters every single time when I move these to other places? Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

BTW, I want to use the stuff I created as a tool and share with others if every time the parameters have been setted again, it is really annoying.

Comment: Are you changing the folder structure within the project? e.g. from Game/BPs/MyBP to Game/OtherFolder/MyBP? UE uses soft references in its assets, and you can't simply move them around outside of UE - search for 'migrating assets'

Comment: hey, this helped me a lot, and I find what's wrong based on your answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you change the structure of a project, Unreal engine leaves behind small files called "Redirectors". These preserve the structure of your project and are mere hookup points so references are not lost.

You can finish the job by right-clicking in the folders you refactored and selecting "Fix-up redirections in folder". This will remove the redirectors and perform a thorough run through the blueprints, structs and data assets to make the references consistent.

Please note that sometimes, interfaces can stop recognizing certain types (structs in particular). In those cases, the workaround is to just change the attribute type to the same struct and recompile the interface.

Copy-pasting files from one project to another can be done directly from the Explorer, as long as you copy all the references (the ones that are not copied will be broken) and paste them in exactly the same hierarchy. This means you need to copy the files and replicate the folder structure starting from the base Content folder. It can be tricky, yes, but you can just right click > Asset Actions > Migrate, which will copy the files preserving both the folder structure and the references.